# Is it possible to stream endless audio in flutter?

Tags: flutter, cross-platform, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm developing an online radio app in flutter and I'm looking for an audio player which supports endless audio streaming from a certain URL (e.g. http://us4.internet-radio.com:8258/stream?type=http). It is highly desirable for it to be supported both on iOS and Android.

Is there such an option in flutter?

From what I've found, there are no solutions that satisfy me needs. The closest one is `fluttery_audio`, but, apparently, it doesn't support endless audio.

I apologize for my jargon with 'endless audio streaming', I'm not really sure what's the technical name for an online radio player is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with flutter_webview_plugin and hide it.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin

```
final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(url, hidden: true);
```

Comment: That’s nice. Thank you. Is there an option to play audio in the background with this plugin?

Comment: ohh I don't think so. :(

Comment: That's still OK for what I'm trying to achieve, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try flutter radio package, Check working app here...
[Source code](https://cutt.ly/flutter-radio)

[image: Watch the video]